# How to stop application for blast if no network is available?

Tags: android

I have a class, which does not extend activity, that shows an error if no Internet connection is available

If Internet is available it works fine, but when Internet is not available or if the server is busy, then the application force closes. How do I prevent this? How can I print catch block message in main activity class?

How to  stop application from crashing if there is no network is available?

```
   public class AgAppHelperMethods   {


  private static final String LOG_TAG = null;
  public static   String[][] AgAppXMLParser( String parUrl) {



    String _node,_element;
    String[][] xmlRespone = null;
    try {

            String url = "www.xxxx.com";
            URL finalUrl = new URL(url);    


            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =   
       DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new  
        InputSource(finalUrl.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            _node=new String();
            _element = new String();
            xmlRespone = new String[list.getLength()][2];


            for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++)
                {
                    Node value=list.item(i).      getChildNodes().item(0);
                    _node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
                    _element=value.getNodeValue();
                    xmlRespone[i][0] = _node;
                    xmlRespone[i][1] = _element;

                }//end for

        }//end try









 catch (Exception e)
 {
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connection Error NET NOT WORKING", e);
     }





    return xmlRespone;         

}



        public class LoginScreen extends Activity implements Serializable {


public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.agapplogin);
          btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public  void  
          onClick(View     view) {
            postLoginData();

             public void postLoginData()

{
             xmlRespone = AgAppHelperMethods.AgAppXMLParser( "www.xxx.com);


        Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),   
      Activity2.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("xmlResponee", xmlRespone.toString());
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        //i.putExtra("OBJECT", xmlRespone)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if internet is available or not using this snippet,

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetworkInfo == null) {

            Toast.makeText(Photos_Activity.this,
                    "Network Not Connected...Please Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            if (activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {

                //Here you can perform your task when internet is connected 

            } else if (activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {

                Toast.makeText(Photos_Activity.this,
                        "Network is connecting Now please patient",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
```

Don't forget to add this permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: if you want to quit your application when the Internet is not connected meas, use System.exit(0); inside the if block.

Comment: non o i check it imean if i call http url and if no server avaiilable or server busy how i handlee this?

Comment: u  not getting suppose if i enter invalid user id password for accesss server url is "www.123.com"+"username.text" +"password.text"  is this input is wrong or server busy how i handle this??

Comment: @SmartGuy: so you check the response code of the server, and display a toast message according to it.

Comment: i didnot jmean interner is not avaibale  imean if server is not avaibale how to handle this?

Comment: @SmartGuy: i hope may this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860098/how-to-find-server-unavailable-in-android

Comment: but how i show error message in main screen? bcoz the clas which use http connection is not extent activity hwo i pass error mesaage to main class which display in a toast?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check first network availability then go for further process

this function may help full to you and Add required permission

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean outcome = false;

        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo tempNetworkInfo : networkInfos) {

                if (tempNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    outcome = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return outcome;
    }
```

Comment: i did this imean if no httpserver available or server busy suppose i call this url"www.123.com"  if server not avaibale or if no response how i handle this??

Comment: then you may check first your response

Comment: suppose i call url and url is not exist then qpplication is blast how i stop this??

Comment: where you getting Error that line put try{ code here }catch(Exception e) and read

Comment: thats my point i access url in AgAppHelperMethods  class which ch is not extent activity if error occur in that clas how i show that error in LoginScreen classs?